# Checking Winner in connect 4 C++ Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have been at these piece of code for hours and I'm stuck on the algorithm needed for this piece of code. I hate being that one guy that posts the entire code but I feel it is necessary so you can understand it. I am completely stuck on how to check for a winner. I was thinking it could be done recursively, but after talking with some people they said this is not the best way to do it. I am completely stumped on how to solve this.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

/**
 * @brief Check if a winner exists
 *
 * @param pBoard The board
 * @param colSize The column size
 * @param rowSize The row size
 *
 * @return The character of the winner, 0 for no winner, and 't' for a tie
 */
char checkWinner(char** pBoard, int colSize, int rowSize, int winSize) {
    // TODO

    **This is where the algorithm needs to go.**

    return 0;
}
/**
 * @brief Place a piece onto the board
 *
 * @param pBoard The game board
 * @param colSize The column size
 * @param rowSize the row size
 * @param columnSelection The column selection
 * @param player The players characterS
 *
 * @return True if the piece was placed, else false
 */
bool placePiece(char** pBoard, int colSize, int rowSize, int columnSelection, char player)
{
    // TODO
    int row = rowSize-1;

    while (pBoard[row][columnSelection]!= ' ' && row > 0){
        row--;
    }

    std::cout << row << std::endl;

    if (pBoard[row][columnSelection] == ' ') {
        pBoard[row][columnSelection] = player;
        return true;
    }   else{
        std::cout << "The space is full." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

}

/**
 * @brief Print out the game board
 *
 * @param pBoard The game board
 * @param colSize The column size
 * @param rowSize The row size
 */
void printBoard(char** pBoard, int colSize, int rowSize) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= rowSize; ++i){
    std::cout << "|" << i;
    }

    std:: cout << "|" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; ++i){
        std::cout << "|";
        for (int j = 0; j < colSize; ++j){
            std::cout << pBoard[i][j] << "|";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    bool running = true;
    printf("Welcome to connect four!\n");
    srand (time(NULL));

    int32_t connectedPiecesToWin = 0;
    int32_t rowSize = 0;
    int32_t colSize = 0;

    // setup game
    std::cout << "How many connected pieces does it take to win?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> connectedPiecesToWin;

    rowSize = connectedPiecesToWin + 2;
    colSize = connectedPiecesToWin + 3;

    std::cout << "You have selected " << connectedPiecesToWin << " in a row with a game board of " << colSize
<< " x " << rowSize << std::endl;

    // setup board
    char** pBoard = NULL; // TODO create the game board


    // initialize board

    pBoard = new char*[rowSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; ++i){
        pBoard[i] = new char[colSize];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rowSize; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < colSize; ++j){
            pBoard[i][j]= ' ';
        }
    }


    // play
    char winner = 0;
    char player = 'p';
    do
    {
        int columnChoice = 0;

        do
        {
            if (player == 'p')
            {
                printBoard(pBoard, colSize, rowSize);
                std::cout << "Player's column: ";
                std::cin >> columnChoice;
            }
            else
            {
                // computers turn
                columnChoice = rand() % colSize;
            }
        } while (!placePiece(pBoard, colSize, rowSize, columnChoice, player));

        winner = checkWinner(pBoard, colSize, rowSize, connectedPiecesToWin);
        player = (player == 'c') ? 'p' : 'c';
    } while (running && winner == 0);

    printBoard(pBoard, colSize, rowSize);

    if (winner == 't')
    {
        std::cout << "Too bad, the game was a tie!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (winner == 'c')
    {
        std::cout << "Oh man, you lost to a computer that randomly places pieces!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Congrats! You won!" << std::endl;
    }

    // cleanup
    // TODO cleanup the board

    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; ++i){
        delete[] pBoard[i];
    }
    delete[] pBoard;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new char*[rowSize]` - avoid using `new`, never use array `new`. Use a `vector` instead. That said, you can surely reduce the example and thus stop being "that guy", for example there's no need for input or output at all. Just set up a hardcoded board and then the winner checking code.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I would have loved to do that, I should have mentioned, yes this was a homework assignment, no, I did not write 75% of this code. If given the choice I would have written this entire thing differently and stuck checkWinner as a boolean function rather than a char function.

Comment: So, in order to fulfill your homework requirements, you intentionally violated the site rules here? Or was it laziness to extract a minimal example? There are actually reasons for those rules, in particular they help you to focus on the problem without having other stuff around it distracting you and others.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I apologize if I offended you. But I did not want anyone to do my homework for me, I needed ideas on how to best implement the algorithm I was thinking about all night. I was working on that algorithm for about 8 hours. It was late, I used the other resources available to me before turning here. And all the responses were more helpful than my actual tutor lab here. So I apologize for seeking help. I'm not going to give up on this assignment because it's been turned in, I want to become a better programmer and thus reaching out for help. I still want to finish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brute force approach is to test every cell to see if it's connected to connectedPiecesToWin pieces in any of the valid directions so first write a routine that will return true if the cell at 0,0 is a winning cell:

- pick an offset to search, say -1,-1 to search diagonally
- for that offset:

  - check to see if the cell at that offset from the target cell is the same colour.
  - if yes, increment a counter and perform the same test again 
    at that offset from the offset cell (little bit of recursion here)
  - stop when you hit a wall or the number of same-colour cells is greater than or equal to connectedPiecesToWin. \edit
- pick the next offset (-1,0), (0,-1), (1,1), etc.
- if you search all eight directions and don't get a win return false.

That routine is then the key to either searching the whole board for a winning cell, or just checking whether the move just made has created a win.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: No you're not missing anything, that was right on point. I just didn't know how to go about executing it is all. I turned in the assignment as is since I already did 90% of the work. It was just this crucial part I was missing is all.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is clearly homework, I'll give you the naive strategy without providing actual code.

For any position **(x,y)**, there's a winner if there are four pieces of the same colour arranged horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.  So let's look at the case for RED winning on horizontal:

```
(x,y)    (x+1,y)  (x+2,y)  (x+3,y)
RED      RED      RED      RED
```

Similar co-ordinate arithmetic applies for the other arrangements.  So you really just need to look each position in the array from **(0,0)** to **(width-4,height-4)** (except for one of the diagonal cases which operates on a different range) and do the "win-test" beginning at that position.

A smarter win-test will only examine the area around the most recently-played piece.

Comment: Ok, so if I am understanding correctly. 

If I am going vertically I would go (x,y) (x, y+1) (x, y+2) (x, y+3) correct?

Comment: And I obviously have to find another way to check it diagonally, but I guess my question is, how do I pass in player if I am not given the option to do it?? I feel like I would have to do the same thing twice, once for player, and once for computer.

Comment: I think your function is supposed to return which player wins (if any).  It's even written right there in the doxygen comments for the return value.  I don't quite understand how there could be a _tie_ in a valid game, however.

Comment: @Sailanarmo It becomes easier if you write another function that checks one given position and use that in `checkWinner`. (This function would also be useful for automatically picking better positions.)

Comment: @paddy, so I understood what you were telling me. However, I could not find a way to execute it. I turned in the assignment as is at that point since it was due at midnight. Can you explain how I would go about finding position based around the most recently-played piece? When I was in the tutor lab at our school they told me to go from (0,0) which would be top left, but in my head it makes more sense to start from any space at the bottom?

Comment: @molbdnilo, I guess I am confused on what it means by checking position. I think this way my downfall last night since I failed to get the assignment to do checkWinner.

Comment: It doesn't really matter where you start.  You still need to examine the whole board.  That function, given its signature, is clearly not intended to do per-move localised win-tests.  The only advantage in starting at the bottom is you are more likely to exit the function early (in the case of a win).  Of course, you can avoid doing tests if a particular element is not filled, so that "optimization" isn't particularly relevant.  For programs like this, you should be biased towards code clarity rather than speed.